# How to find cpanel server url name to use for a XMLHttp Post request

Tags: file-upload, server, xmlhttprequest, cpanel

I am new to servers and Cpanel. I am building a chrome extension where I have to upload html files to my server, but am unsure as to what the url should be when doing an XMLHttpRequest().If I just type in the name of my website which Cpanel hosts, including the username and password, would that work?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is to use the cPanel/WHM API version 1 or 2.

This link should provide you more details on how to use cPanel API, specifically for uploading files:

https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/SDK/cPanel+API+2+Functions+-+Fileman%3A%3Auploadfiles

Answer (score 0):

**Could you Please explain in few more words?**

I think you are asking 
Can i upload files to cpanel! just by url and cpanel username and password ? by using the XMLHttpRequest() ex : from the extension?

If yes.
For private use you can Use PHP FTP classes to run in host
like example.com/myownftp/
or
Cpanel ftp example.com:port for ftp : username and password

---

Or You can Achieve it by making a script to upload the files to your hosting server its Simple.. PHP is great to do.

I would like to know whether i replied to Your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use PHP as Google Chrome extensions only allow Javascript.

Comment: I mean,
you can get a Server which support PHP and Make a call to PHP Server via the Javascript..
its possible? right.